# Use of present perfect tense or past perfect tense

Tags: grammar

Which tense should be used if I want to indicate that, Mr A, who has passed away, was an engineer working in different countries before his death? ‘Mr A has worked in Singapore, India & Hong Kong’ or ‘Mr A had worked in Singapore, India & Hong Kong’?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U,  Please see the many posts we have about perfect constructions/

Comment: Why not simple past?   ‘Mr. A worked in Singapore, India & Hong Kong.’   P.S. It’s typical to put a ‘**.**’ after ‘Mr’, because it is an abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

Unless he is alive and present I would not use any perfect tense, past or present.

The simplest is always the best.

‘Mr A *worked* in Singapore, India & Hong Kong’